# Plone: Default front page does not have Add New menu

Tags: plone

We are using Plone 4.2 (but problem applies to earlier versions as well).

We have a folder called news containing all our news items, and have a News tab in the navigation to go to the News default .
We set the default front page of our site to our News folder, by configuring Zope Management Interface -> Plone site at / -> Properties -> default_page.   This works as every time a user first goes to our site or clicks on the Site title at the top of our site, he will see the News default view.   However, there is no "Add new" menu at the top of this News default view.    When the user clicks on the News tab of navigation, the News default view has the "Add new" menu for user to add new news item to the folder.

Is it possible to make the default front page of the site show the same display as the News tab of the navigation?

Thank you very much in anticipation.

cmgui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On siteroot add a contenttype 'Link', enter a title of your choice and set the destination to '/yourSiteId/yourNewsFolderId', make sure it is published, set the Link as default-view of your site.

Comment: Thank Ida Ebikes, I　ｔｒｉｅｄ　ｙｏｕｒ　ｍｅｔｈｏｄ　ｂｕｔ　ｉｔ　ｄｉｄｎ＇ｔ　ｗｏｒｋ．　　Ｉｎｓｔｅａｄ　ｏｆ　ｄｉｓｐｌａｙｉｎｇ　／ｙｏｕｒＳｉｔｅＩｄ／ｙｏｕｒＮｅｗｓＦｏｌｄｅｒｉｄ，ｔｈｅ　ｄｅｆａｕｌｔ　ｐａｇｅ　ｓｈｏｗｓ　ｔｈｅ　Ｖｉｅｗ　ｐａｇｅ　ｏｆ　ｔｈｅ　ｌｉｎｋ　ｐａｇｅ，　ｉ．ｅ．　link title
The link address is: ／ｙｏｕｒＳｉｔｅＩｄ／ｙｏｕｒＮｅｗｓＦｏｌｄｅｒｉｄ

Comment: That's right, but only for users who have the edit right on the link (in order to give them a chance to edit the link instead of being redirected :), others will be directed immediately to the target. That's usually what you want. Will that suffice your requirements?

Comment: Thank you Thank Ida Ebikes.   The reason for this post is to have the "Add new" menu in the default front page.  So we actually want our logged-in users to be able to add News items (we give them Add permissions to the News folder) -- that is why we need the "Add new" in the default front page.   Of course, the user can click News in the navigation and then the News page will have the "Add new" menu --- but this is an extra step and confusing to users.    Also, I tried removing all permissions for the logged-in users to the News folder, and your method still does not work.  Thank you.

Comment: Did you give edit-rights on siteroot for your members? Cou can inhibit the acess-inheritage on the link itself then via it's sharing tab. Otherwise you must have done some more customz you didn't mention yet, works on a vanilla plonesite. Very welcome.

Comment: Thank you Ida Ebikes.  No inherit.  Root folder only View rights.  I removed all rights except View.   Still didn't work.  No customization.    Are you using the latest Plone 4.2 ?     Thank you.

Comment: you are right Ebikes.  I tried on a pristine Plone 4.2 and it worked.   Now trying to troubleshoot my production site. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much Ebikes.  I found the problem.  In Type Settings -> Link->Redirect immediately to link target wasn't selected.  Now all is well.  Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible - at least not with some customizations to code and configurations. "What you see" and "what you can do" is usually tied to particular interfaces or portal_types and making something appear in the same way as within another context is basically not supported of ouf the box.

Comment: Thank you esaelPsnoroMoN for your reply.   Do you think using template for the default front page can add the "Add new" menu to the page?   Also, do you think it does not seem right that the default front page (set to News) does not show the "Actions", "Add new" menus but when user clicks on News in navigation, he can see "Actions", "Add new" (if we give users Add permissions)?    Why the difference?   My users will be confused.   I'm thinking of submitting this as a bug report to plone dev.   Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

if using dexterity:

when you first get into ZMI click on 'properties' tab and change the 'default page' to the page you want displayed.
this can be a folderish item and will have whatever  'add' permissions you define when creating new content type.

Answer (score 0):

if you can't get the "add" options for a content type, you can use TALES conditions to control who can see specific items on your webpage. jsut  around what you want to control.  one example, which does not show an "add event" link to anon users.

```
<span tal:condition="not: context/@@plone_portal_state/anonymous">
                <a tal:attributes="href string:../createObject?type_name=Event" tal:content="string:add new event"></a>
            </span>
```